# My Ubuntu mail server rejects incoming mails

Tags: server, 14.10, email, postfix, mail

i had installed my ubuntu server, postfix and rest using the link 
https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-14.10-with-apache-php-myqsl-pureftpd-bind-postfix-doveot-and-ispconfig

But incoming mails are getting rejected.

For your information, I am able to send mails to any domain.

here is my postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
mydestination = hardcube.net, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = hardcube.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
owner_request_special = no
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_map$
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
relayhost =
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Below is the mail which i received while replying to that mail.

Technical details of permanent failure:

```
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain hardcube.net by smtp.europe.secureserver.net. [188.121.52.56].
The error that the other server returned was:
550 5.1.1 <hariharan.gopal@hardcube.net> Recipient not found.  <http://x.co/irbounce>
```

---

New info:

[image]

Is the above settings correct?

Comment: PLease check with your admin as this is nothing Ubuntu related

Comment: Hi, I only created this setup. Im not sure what to do next. So please guide me on this.

Comment: Your DNS MX record isn't pointing to your server.

Comment: Postfix is not matching the recipient email to a user in your system, do you have email users setup in ISPConfig?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. How could I add DNS MX record.

Comment: Connection is refused when i tried "telnet xxxxx 110" and "telnet xxxx 143"

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP doesn't recognize hardcube.net which traces to ip-166-62-12-213.ip.secureserver.net (166.62.12.213)

If you own this domain, you need to work with your ISP to get the DNS records updated, If you've done so, It can take a couple of days (maybe more?) for the records to propagate across the net.

If you ask them how long it will take they will tell you.